# ERROR: Import .txt to table reports missing data for column - POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Importing a .txt file into the postgreSQL database table, but I am getting an error:

ERROR:

missing data for column "filename" SQL state: 22P04

**My table structure is:**

**Table Name** : testdata_table

**Cols Names are:**

fileid (NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY)

sno_id (NOT NULL)

file_name(NOT NULL)

**The .txt contents are**

19876

derek1.txt

19876

derek2.txt

19876 should be saved in sno_id and derek1.txt under filename and so on.

Tested using *insert command* on one to two data and did not face any issues in uploading the contents to table

**SQL**

insert into testdata_table (sno_id, file_name) values (19876,derek1.txt)

insert into testdata_table (sno_id, file_name) values (19876,derek2.txt)

select * from testdata_table

fileid   sno_id      file_name

```
1   19876       derek1.txt

2   19876       derek2.txt
```

(fileid is autogenerated)

**PROBLEM STARTS HERE**

When you right click a tablename (in this case is testdata_table ), there is an option to upload the data (using Import/Export)

I chose Import to upload the .txt file into testdata_table and in the cols category I choose only **sno_id and file_name**

Only the data for **sno_id** and **file_name** are in the .txt file and **fileid** is auto generated

There is no space after each text (ie 19876 or derek1.txt)

When I try to upload the contents in the table, I get the error as "missing data for column file_name"

Why encountering this error ?

Comment: This question is a mess. Is the data in the text file really all in one column or is it in rows of fileid, filename? Show the `INSERT` command you used? Define what `Import` means and what client was used? You refer to `filename` but the error refers to `file_name`, which is correct? A guess as to the error is you are using `COPY` and only supplying two of the three fields needed.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have edited the question. The data in the text file is under one col only.

Comment: You still have not mentioned the actual client used, but I am going to guess pgAdmin4.  The problem seems to be fairly evident, you have a text file with a single column that you are trying to put into two columns in the database. You need to create a text file with the data in two columns separated by a delimiter.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, a very clear mistake from my end. Such a silly one. Thank you Adrian.